# How can i pass text box value in href

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi all i am having my input text which was declared as follows

```
<input name="text1" type="text" id="text1" value="textbox 1" onBlur="toggleVisibility(this.name);">
```

I would like to pass the `text` values in my `href` . I tried the below but i am unable to get the value can any one help me

```
<a href="http://paymycheck.info/federalregulartaxcalculator.aspx?id="+document.getElementById('text1').value;target="_blank"  style="text-decoration:underline; text-align:right; color:#222; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; font-weight:normal;"> Unsubscribe </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this...using javascript function...

```
 <input type="text" id="myText"/>
<a href="javascript:RedirectToSecondPage()">click here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function RedirectToSecondPage()
{
   var input = document.getElementById('myText');
   var value = input ? input.value : 'defaultText';

   window.location.href = 'mySecond.asp?MyText=' + escape(value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible in the way i am passing with out javascript function

Comment: You can wrap it all in a form and show the "pointer" (hand) cursor on the submit button, so it actually submits the form and the value. If you want to use a plain anchor (a) element, you'll have to use the JavaScript.

Comment: If i use the script too i am unable to view the passed value in browser

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the actual value you can do something like this:

```
<input name="text1" type="text" id="text1" value="textbox 1" onBlur="toggleVisibility(this.name);">
<a href="javascript:document.location.href='http://paymycheck.info/federalregulartaxcalculator.aspx?id=' + document.getElementById('text1').value">Unsubscribe</a>
```

However this may have unwanted side effects (e.g. spaces appear in the URL as actual spaces).
If you can change the name of the input you might consider doing it via a proper form:

```
<form id="myform" action="http://aaapaymycheck.info/federalregulartaxcalculator.aspx" method="get">
    <input name="id" type="text" id="text1" value="textbox 1" onBlur="toggleVisibility(this.name);">
</form>

<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('myform').submit()">Unsubscribe</a>
```